# npm rc-form package getFieldDecorator method throws Warning for `defaultValue` although I'm not using it as an option

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, package, rc-form

I have rc-form 2.4.8 version, and I'm using **getFieldDecorator** method,
which throws

> Warning: `defaultValue` is invalid for `getFieldDecorator` will set `value`, please use `option.initialValue` instead.

I'm not using **defaultValue** anywhere in code

```
{getFieldDecorator('select', {
                     rules: [{
                        required: true,
                        message: 'Select the range'
                    }],
                     initialValue: ''
                })(
                    <Select
                     ref={((input) => { this.focusRef = input; })}/>
                   )
```

Any ideas why this happens?

Comment: OP - add a working example using jsfiddle or something.

Comment: I tried with https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-dawn-95jpm 
but **Console was cleared**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally, after lots of research, I find a solution! Using
`getFieldProps(name, option)`
method instead of   `getFieldDecorator(name, option)`
 fixes issue.

[rc-form documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rc-form#getfieldpropsname-option-object--valuepropname-trigger-validatetrigger-)